# How can I deal with "internal server error" during installer?

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

I'm trying to install, but it gives me this error:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@.... and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
>   error. More information about this error may be available in the
>   server error log. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered
>   while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

LOG:

```
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/500.shtml, referer: my-domain. /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/500.shtml, referer: my-domain. /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/404.shtml, referer: my-domain. /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-domain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/favicon.ico, referer: my-domain. /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-domain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/404.shtml
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/demo
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/404.shtml
File does not exist: /home/master-folder/public_html/my-domain/robots.txt
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this before displaying the first step of install or once you start the install?

If this is during the installation, it might mean that your timeout is configured in a way that it considers the page dead before it properly has the time to finish the install.

You might want to workaround that by either changing the configuration to allow longer running pages, or try installing from the commandline (using wp-cli).

If it is before displaying anything, it might be that you haven't used the proper url or didn't put the files at the right place or...

If you follow the steps on that page, it should get you a running civi:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress

Comment: This occurs during installation, modify max_execution_time times and the error persists.
Do you have something to do consult you use another database?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically file permission issue. You need to check permission for those files that are responsible for this error.